# Running two Nodejs servers on single Azure VM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, server, virtual-machine

[image: Azure Screenshot of my VM]

I have one VM running with one node js server on 80 port. Its running quite fine. Now I am running another nodejs server locally on VM with port 3000. Its running locally on VM as well along with 80 port.
So,

localhost : 80

localhost : 3000

is working like charm. The problem is that the URL which is live e.g http://zubair.cloudapp.net is only running 80 port, how should I run 3000 port server using this url? I thought of something like this :
http://zubair.cloudapp.net:3000 but it didnt work.

Note : I have also added 3000 port in endpoints which is not shown in the picture but still it didnt work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The endpoints in Azure Portal are configured for the Azure Cloud tier outside of the VM instance, you can try to enable the inbound port in firewall in VM, just like @evilSnobu's solution. You can refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx for more info. Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Looking into it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a Windows VM. Have you added a rule for 3000/TCP inbound in the OS firewall?

You need both the Endpoint definition and the Windows Firewall rule for **3000/TCP** (inbound) to make that work.

Comment: Oh I didnt do that. Let me add that in OS firewall. Will update you. Thanks